# xsl: how to use parameter inside "match"?

Tags: xslt

My xsl has a parameter

```
<xsl:param name="halfPath" select="'halfPath'"/>
```

I want to use it inside match

```
<xsl:template match="Element[@at1='value1' and not(@at2='{$halfPath}/another/half/of/the/path')]"/>
```

But this doesn't work. I guess a can not use parameters inside ''. How to fix/workaround that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could use a conditional instruction inside the template:

```
<xsl:template match="Element[@at1='value1']">
  <xsl:if test="not(@at2=concat($halfPath,'/another/half/of/the/path'))">
    .. do something
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

You just need to be aware that this template will handle all elements that satisfy the first condition. If you have a different template that handles elements that match the first, but not the second, then use an `<xsl:choose>`, and put the other template's body in the `<xsl:otherwise>` block.

Or, XSLT2 can handle it as is if you can switch to an XSLT2 processor.

Comment: also I have to use string() on my parameters, it doesn't work without that by some reason... string($halfPath)

Comment: You can use a conditional inside a template, but the code shown above is not correct. A `test` expression isn't an attribute value template, so the `{}` don't cause substitution. Instead you're testing whether `@at2` is equal to a literal string `{$halfPath}/...`, which is not what you want. See @MichaelKay's answer for more details.

Comment: @LarsH: Good point- I'd copied the condition verbatim from the question, I hadn't noticed it wasn't valid anyway. Fixed it now.

Comment: Observation: When an identity template was used to copy a very large XML file to modifying only a very few instances of attributes that occurred throughout the file, with at least one XSLT 1.0 processor, using xsl:if or xsl:choose inside the template was orders of magnitude slower than using a match expression (using a hardcoded literal to work around inability to use a variable/parameter in the match expression). The point? The cost of not being able to use a variable in the match expression could strongly influence what XSLT 2.0 upgrade difficulties are worth enduring to achieve one's goals.

Answer (score 8):

**The [XSLT 1.0 W3C Specification forbids referencing variables/parameters inside a match pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Defining-Template-Rules).**:

> "It is an error for the value of the
>   match attribute to contain a
>   VariableReference"

**There is no such limitation in XSLT 2.0, so use XSLT 2.0**.

If due to unsurmountable reasons using XSLT2.0 isn't possible, put the complete body of the `<xsl:template>` instruction inside an `<xsl:if>` where the test in conjunction with the match pattern is equivalent to the XSLT 2.0 match pattern that contains the variable/parameter reference(s).

In a more complicated case where you have more than one template matching the same kind of node but with different predicates that reference variables/parameters, then a wrapping `<xsl:choose>` will need to be used instead of a wrapping `<xsl:if>`.

Comment: Sorry for this messy comment. I will remove it. In the meantime I prepared a clean example in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624779/not-possible-to-use-template-parameter-in-the-match-xpath-expression-in-xslt-2-0)

Answer (score 2):

This topic had the answer to my question, but the proposed solution by Flynn1179 was not quite correct for me (YMMV). So try it the way it is suggested by people more expert than me, but if it doesn't work for you, consider how I solved it. I am using xsltproc that only handles XSL version 1.0.

I needed to match `<leadTime hour="0024">`, but use a param: `<xsl:param name="hour">0024</xsl:param>`. I found that:
`<xsl:if test="@hour='{$hour}'">` did not work, despite statements here and elsewhere that this is the required syntax for XSL v.1.0.
Instead, the simpler `<xsl:if test="@hour=$hour">` did the job.

One other point: it is suggested above by Dimitre that you put template inside if statement. xsltproc complained about this: instead I put the if statement inside the template:

```
<xsl:template match="leadTime">
  <xsl:if test="@hour=$leadhour">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 for noticing that the accepted answer's code was wrong, and giving a working solution. BTW Dimitre wasn't suggesting that you put a template inside an `if` statement; he was saying to put the *body* (the contents) of a template inside an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 you can refer to global variables within a match pattern, but the syntax is simpler than your guess:

```
<xsl:template match="Element[@at1='value1' and 
              not(@at2=$halfPath/another/half/of/the/path)]"/>
```

rather than

```
<xsl:template match="Element[@at1='value1' and 
              not(@at2='{$halfPath}/another/half/of/the/path')]"/>
```

Also, the semantics are not what you appear to be expecting: a variable referenced on the lhs of "/" must contain a node-set, not a fragment of an XPath expression.