# Variable in xsl:template matching pattern

Tags: xslt

**Given**

An XSLT stylesheet with a global variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="lang" select="/response/str[@name='lang']"/>
```

**Question**

Where from comes the limitation that using variables in predicates is incorrect in the `xsl:template` matching pattern, but is acceptable in `xsl:apply-templates` selecting pattern?

```
<!-- throws compilation error, at least in libxslt --> 
<xsl:template match="list[@name='item_list'][$lang]"/>

<!-- works as expected --> 
<xsl:template match="list[@name='item_list'][/response/str[@name='lang']]"/>

<!-- works as expected --> 
<xsl:template match="response">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="list[@name='item_list'][$lang]">
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is the limitation, but are you sure your `$lang` contains string value (or numeric) but not some node set?

Comment: @yuri, it does contain a node set, but I do not see a reason why a node set is not allowed in the context.

Comment: I can't tell you details as to why the restriction was specified in XSLT 1.0 but I can tell you that it is gone in XSLT 2.0 so you might want to consider to move to that version of the language and one of its implementations like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML.

Comment: @martin-honnen, I use libxslt from python, and used to see the same limitation in php a long time ago. It has never been a show stopper to me, but now I just decided to find out the reason. From Java or .Net I would definitely use Saxon, but XSLT 1.0 actually covers all my needs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xsl: how to use parameter inside "match"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117460/xsl-how-to-use-parameter-inside-match)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Variables are not allowed to be used in match expressions in XSLT 1.0.**

From the XSLT 1.0 specification: [Defining Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Defining-Template-Rules)

> It is an error for the value of the match attribute to contain a
>   VariableReference.

**Variables are allowed in match expressions in XSLT 2.0**.

From the XSLT 2.0 specification: [Syntax of Patterns](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#pattern-syntax)

> Patterns may start with an id  FO or key function call, provided that
>   the value to be matched is supplied as either a literal or a reference
>   to a variable or parameter, and the key name (in the case of the key
>   function) is supplied as a string literal. These patterns will never
>   match a node in a tree whose root is not a document node.

Comment: Thanks! Right before asking I looked at exactly that section of the spec, but somehow overlooked the sentence you quoted. I need to sleep better!

Comment: @newtover: P.S. you also asked why a variable reference "is acceptable in xsl:apply-templates selecting pattern". The answer is that the select in `xsl:apply-templates` is not a pattern but an XPath expression. Patterns look a lot like XPath expressions but they are not the same. This variable reference limitation is one difference (in XSLT 1.0).

Comment: Mads, I don't think your statement about when variables are allowed in match expressions is quite accurate, based on my reading of the spec. I think you can just say "Variables are allowed in match expressions in XSLT 2.0" even if they refer to a document node. It's just that patterns containing key() and id() function calls will never match a node in a tree whose root is not a document node... but that doesn't limit what the value of a variable in the pattern can be.

Comment: Thanks for making the edit. I also meant to say, I don't think the quoted paragraph tells us anything about variables being allowed in match patterns (except that you can't use a variable for the name of a key). It's really only about restrictions on `id()` and `key()` function calls in patterns.

Comment: The question then arises, what part of the spec tells us that variables are allowed in match patterns? I assume the answer is that the syntax of patterns, including the production for `PredicateList`, references symbols that are specified as allowing `VarRef` in their expansion somewhere down the chain.

Comment: It looks like PredicateList and IdKeyPattern cover all the symbols in the syntax of patterns that allow a VarRef. That would imply that variables are not allowed in match patterns outside of predicates and id/key function calls. I didn't know that. (I can't think of a reason why you'd want to use a variable in any other way, e.g. "bare", in a match pattern.)