# XSLT - Remove Nodes with no child node matching specific values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am very new to XSLT, I started reading about it yesterday and I'm stuck. I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Menu>
  <Function>
    <Name>ViewHome</Name>
    <Roles>
      <Role>Finance</Role>
      <Role>Advisor</Role>
      <Role>Admin</Role>
    </Roles>
  </Function>
  <Function>
    <Name>ViewStaff</Name>
    <ChildFunctions>
      <Function>
        <Name>StaffFunction1</Name>
        <Roles>
          <Role>Finance</Role>
        </Roles>
      </Function>
      <Function>
        <Name>StaffFunction2</Name>
        <Roles>
          <Role>Admin</Role>
        </Roles>
      </Function>
      <Function>
        <Name>StaffFunction3</Name>
        <Roles>
          <Role>Advisor</Role>
        </Roles>
      </Function>
    </ChildFunctions>
  </Function>
  <Function>
    <Name>ViewDiary</Name>
    <Roles>
      <Role>Advisor</Role>
    </Roles>
  </Function>
</Menu>
```

Which I would like transformed to show only those functions (parent or child) that contain a specified role or roles. So that if Finance and Advisor roles are applied the output would be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Menu>
  <Function>
    <Name>ViewHome</Name>
    <Roles>
      <Role>Finance</Role>
      <Role>Advisor</Role>
    </Roles>
  </Function>
  <Function>
    <Name>ViewStaff</Name>
    <ChildFunctions>
      <Function>
        <Name>StaffFunction1</Name>
        <Roles>
          <Role>Finance</Role>
        </Roles>
      </Function>
      <Function>
        <Name>StaffFunction3</Name>
        <Roles>
          <Role>Advisor</Role>
        </Roles>
      </Function>
    </ChildFunctions>
  </Function>
  <Function>
    <Name>ViewDiary</Name>
    <Roles>
      <Role>Advisor</Role>
    </Roles>
  </Function>
</Menu>
```

I have looked at other posts on this site, but can't generate the required output. The xsl I have been using is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:variable name="rolesList">Advisor Finance</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Function[not(descendant::Role[contains($rolesList, .)])]"/>

<!--
    <xsl:template match="Function[not(descendant::Role='Finance')]"/>
-->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ultimately the rolesList variable will be supplied through code. I just wanted to get the transform working. If I use the commented out template match for just 'Finance' role I get the expected results. 
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 here? In XSLT 1.0 it is not possible to use variables in template matches, but it is in XLST 2.0. As an aside, in your template match, you are referring to **roleList** but the variable is actually named **rolesList**!

Comment: Tim, I have no restriction on which version of XSL to use. Thanks for noticing the typo.

Comment: Can you instead specify the roles that should _not_ appear in the output?

Comment: @TimC *"In XSLT 1.0 it is not possible to use variables in template matches"* Beg pardon?

Comment: I didn't phrase that properly. It should be read as "you can't use a variable in the `match` attribute of an `xsl:template` command."

Comment: @TimC I'm still not with you.

Comment: Tim is right I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839048/variable-in-xsltemplate-matching-pattern

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Defining-Template-Rules where it says "It is an error for the value of the match attribute to contain a VariableReference"

Comment: Okay, my bad: I should have tested this with more than one processor. It works fine with libxslt and Xalan; only Saxon objects.

Comment: Yes, the XSLT 1.0 spec doesn't allow it, but some implementations do.

Comment: @MichaelKay It *is* a very peculiar limitation. Was it really meant to apply to predicates as well?

Comment: The restriction was added to the spec at a very late stage before publication. It was added in response to a comment I raised pointing out that use of variables in predicates could lead to circularities (if the initializer of the variable calls apply-templates). Disallowing variables was a quick and easy way of eliminating the problem.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the clarification. I would have thought that eliminating the problem was in the province of stylesheet authors - but I guess it's too late to press the point...

Comment: Yes: they made the wrong decision. You have to remember that XSLT 1.0 was produced in about 18 months and they expected to follow up quickly with a 1.1 that would fix any glitches; disallowing something is a mistake that's easier to correct than allowing it and defining it badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that contains() does not work properly if there is more than one `Role` element, because the function does not expect lists as its second argument.

Note that you provide the list of roles as a whitespace-separated list. Yet, without a Schema it is not recognized as a list type. That is why you have to rely on string functions, as pointed out by @michael.hor257k.

This (i.e. template matches that contain variables) only works with XSLT 2.0, as pointed out by @Tim C.

Use the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:variable name="roles">Finance Advisor</xsl:variable>

   <xsl:template match="Function[count(Roles/Role) = 1 and not(matches($roles,Roles/Role))]"/>

   <xsl:template match="Role[not(matches($roles,.))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Menu>
   <Function>
      <Name>ViewHome</Name>
      <Roles>
         <Role>Finance</Role>
         <Role>Advisor</Role>
      </Roles>
   </Function>
   <Function>
      <Name>ViewStaff</Name>
      <ChildFunctions>
         <Function>
            <Name>StaffFunction1</Name>
            <Roles>
               <Role>Finance</Role>
            </Roles>
         </Function>
         <Function>
            <Name>StaffFunction3</Name>
            <Roles>
               <Role>Advisor</Role>
            </Roles>
         </Function>
      </ChildFunctions>
   </Function>
   <Function>
      <Name>ViewDiary</Name>
      <Roles>
         <Role>Advisor</Role>
      </Roles>
   </Function>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 1.0 using string comparison you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:param name="roleList" select="'|Advisor|Finance|'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Function">
      <xsl:if test="descendant::Role[contains($roleList, concat('|', ., '|'))]">
         <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Role">
      <xsl:if test="contains($roleList, concat('|', ., '|'))">
         <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an internal lookup list:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:my="your-urn-here">

  <my:rolesList>
    <my:role>Advisor</my:role>
    <my:role>Finance</my:role>
  </my:rolesList>


  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Function[not(descendant::Role = document('')/*/my:rolesList/my:role)]"
/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Which I would like transformed to show only those functions (parent or
>   child) that contain a specified role or roles.

I believe your stylesheet does exactly that (**although it shouldn't, and with some processors only - see the comments to the question for more details**).

However it does **not** remove the "other" roles from the list of roles descendant to the functions that have passed the test. For that, you would need to add another template matching Role.

> Ultimately the rolesList variable will be supplied through code

Ideally, the list would be supplied as a node-set (or something that can be turned into a node-set), so that you can make the comparison without resorting to string functions. In XSLT 2.0 there is more flexibility in this aspect, though.