# XSLT check if value contained in a array

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having a template which should only match the element `PRA` if it contains a `<PRA.3>` having the value 101, 103 or 104. My input looks like this:

```
<XML>
   <PRA>
      <PRA.3>101</PRA.3>
      <PRA.6>654</PRA.6>
   </PRA>
   <PRA>
      <!-- does not match -->
      <PRA.3>999</PRA.3>
      <PRA.6>654</PRA.6>
   </PRA>      
</XML>
```

The XSLT which works well:

```
<xsl:template match="PRA[PRA.3='101' or PRA.3='103' or PRA.3='104']">
   <!-- does match if PRA.3 equals 101,103,104 -->
</xsl:template>
```

This works well, but the values 101, 103 and 104 will appear in many more templates and can change.

**Is it possible to add these values to a list and then make a contains?**
Here a sample code I'd like to use:

```
<MYARRAY>101,102,104</MYARRAY>
<xsl:template match="PRA[MYARRAY.contains(PRA.3/text())]">

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: In XSLT2.0 (XPath2.0 in fact) you can simply use the `index-of()` function. Which version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: I'm using XSLT 2.0. I'll have a look at index-of()...

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="index-of((101, 102, 104),101)"/>` returns 1. But how can I put the list (101,102,104) into a variable at the beginning of the XSLT?

Comment: @FiveO By putting the list into a variable at the beginning of your XSLT, of course. ;) `<xsl:variable name="myArray" select="(101,102,104)" />`. It's not possible to use variables in match expressions, though. You'll need to do your test in an `<xsl:if>`.

Comment: I have used variables in match expressions and it works :)

Comment: @biziclop Ah, that's allowed since XSLT 2.0 ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839048/variable-in-xsltemplate-matching-pattern)). Nice!

Comment: Thankfully, I don't know where I'd be without it.

Comment: I had to tokenize it as strings - because my content in STF.3 seems to be a String too. `<xsl:variable name="PRA.3" select="tokenize('101,102,104',',')"/>` and then `PRA[index-of($PRA.3,PRA.3)]`. Any possiblity without the string tokenize?

Comment: `<xsl:variable name="myArray" select="('101','102','104')" />`?

Comment: ok but then I still compare 'strings'. What type is the value if there are no '' around it?

Comment: ('101,102,104') will be a sequence with one string '101,102,104', ('101','102','104') will be a sequence with 3 strings, (101,102,104) will be a sequence of 3 numbers

Comment: ok so this is the second solution with numbers: `<xsl:variable name="PRA.3" select="101,102,104"/>` and `PRA[index-of($PRA.3,number(PRA.3))]`

Comment: This works but only as long as all the values are numbers. As soon as you introduce a value like `101a`, that will never ever match. What's worse, it won't throw an error or anything, it just silently fails to match.

Comment: btw index-of() alone will not work you will have to do  `index-of($PRA.3,number(PRA.3)) gt 0`

Comment: Ok, maybe add your answer as well, then we'll see which answer is the best...

Answer (score 4):

In XSLT 2.0 what you want to do is actually rather simple and does not need contains or index-of:

```
<xsl:variable name="myArray" select="('101','102','104')"/>

<xsl:template match="PRA[PRA.3=$myArray]">

</xsl:template>
```

This will be sufficient.

Comment: I would still compare them as strings unless there is a very good reason to force implicit numeric conversion.

Comment: @biziclop I think your right about that, I updated my answer. The difference is, if you use an array of numbers, this expression would crash if there was a PRE.3 that isn't a number. With strings it would just silently fail... now there are constelations were I'd rather have it crash so...depends on the use case

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that it'd fail silently in both cases. According to the specs when template match patterns are evaluated, all errors are considered recoverable, and the recovery action is simply a no match.