# Simple match with parameter using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This is my xsl code without parameter

```
<xsl:template match="node-name">
 ....
</xsl:template>
```

Now I want to use a parameter instead of `node-name`. So I added:

```
<xsl:param name="someParam"/>
 ...

<xsl:template match="$someParam">
 ....
</xsl:template>
```

However, it doesn't work. On SO I found only one question about parameter in match ([xsl: how to use parameter inside "match"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117460/xsl-how-to-use-parameter-inside-match)) but it has a more complicated case, then I need. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match="*[local-name()=$node-name]"`

Take care with namespaces.

Note also that this isn't allowed in XSLT 1.0, only in 2.0+.

Answer (score 0):

If that is a global parameter, then, if you use an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 9.8 or later or Altova 2017 R3 or later you could consider using a static parameter `<xsl:param name="node-name" static="yes" select="'foo'"/>` and a shadow attribute `<xsl:template _match="{$node-name}">`.