# How to validate only one node with method "document.Validate(ValidationEventHandler, node)"?

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, xmlnode

There is a link to an XML Validation [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5aahf2a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

An extract: Let's have a method:

`document.Validate(ValidationEventHandler, bookNode);`

It validates one node `bookNode`.
But after executing this method, node `bookNode` **is not valid,** because:

`bookNode.SchemaInfo.Validity` returns `NotKnown`.

How can I validate only one node using the method "document.Validate(ValidationEventHandler, node)" ?

Comment: Have a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715626/validating-xml-nodes-not-the-entire-document

Comment: I have seen this link, but it does not answer my question

Comment: You start by saying you have code (or have seen code) that validates a single node.  You conclude by asking how to validate a single node.  Is this a trick question?  Or are you not asking what you really want to know?

Comment: I want to know, How can I validate only one node using the method `document.Validate(ValidationEventHandler, node)` ?

Comment: Validation in MSDN example doesn't work.