# Deserializing part of xml gives element not declared error

Tags: xml, xml-deserialization

I am attempting to deserialize only part of an xml, like in this post - [How to deserialize only part of an XML document in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369792/how-to-deserialize-only-part-of-an-xml-document-in-c-sharp/36615972#36615972).

This works, I get an object back!

But, with a validation error of type "... element is not declared".

Sketchy structre of my xml:

```
<UploadDocument>
  <Document>
    <!-- Inner xml removed-->
  </Document>
</UploadDocument>
```

And the error message is - Document element is not declared.

If I attempt to deserialize the root element - UploadDocument - it just works with no validation errors.

My observation:
When the schema is compiled, the Elements collection has only the root element - UploadDocument.

Comment: The answer, by MiMo, to the following post worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232065/validating-xml-node-over-a-xsd-file

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix for this. The code that I have found is this:

```
<UploadDocument>
<Document>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Document>
</UploadDocument>
```