# How to validate subset of XML, against complete XML schema in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

Complete XML Schema:

```
<xs:schema>
 <xs:element name="Root">
  <xs:element name="Element0" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <xs:element name="Element1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <xs:element name="Element2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Subset Sample XML:

```
<Root>
 <Element1>Sample Text</Element1>
</Root>
```

How can i validate the sample XML against the provided schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating xml nodes, not the entire document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715626/validating-xml-nodes-not-the-entire-document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `System.Xml.Schema` namespace contains the classes to validate XML using XSD.

See this instructions in MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx